# How to remove ".cmd" at the end of each Node.js command in PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, terminal

I have a small issue when I run node commands in PowerShell.

### For Example:

I installed TypeScript globally on Windows OS using npm with the command `npm install -g typescript`. However, when I try to run `tsc --version` it doesn't work!

```
tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But on the other hand, it works when I add `.cmd` at the end of `tsc`, like this: `tsc.cmd --version`.

Is there a way to make the command work without adding `.cmd` at the end? It’s very annoying!